# C# and Data Hiding

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# and .Net in general so this may be a naive thing to ask. But anyway, consider this C# code:

```
class A {
    public int Data {get; set;}
}

class B {
    public A Aval {get; set;}
}
```

The B.Aval property above is returning a reference to its internal A object. As a former C++ programmer, I find this dangerous because by exposing reference to an member object class B violates the principle of data hiding. Nonetheless, this seems to be the normal practice in the C# world.

My question is, if it is at all, why is such a design the usual approach as opposed to returning copies of internal members, which will be much safer in so many ways (including the case of thread safety)?

I understand that even in C++ sometimes good design demands that you do expose class members directly (a **Car** class with **Engine** and **Stereo** objects inside it comes to mind), but it is not the norm as seems to be in C#.

Comment: Did you mean "The B.Aval property above is returning a reference to its internal A object" instead of " ... B object"?

Comment: In C++, would you normally write B.Aval's get method so that it makes a copy of its interal A and then returns the copy?

Comment: Exactly. In C++, in 90% of the cases, a get method will return a copy of a member variable, not a reference (or a pointer).

Comment: I guess my point is your code snippet does not illustrate encapsulation in C#.  Typically you would either wrap & not directly expose internal instances or inherit & optionally override to perform encapsulation in C#.

Comment: I understand that, Steph, but my question, is why don't C# programmer seem to care about encapsulation. In C++ world, encapsulation (that is returning by copy and all that) is always the default design. With C#, why is returning internal references the default approach, although it's less safe?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree - the language makes encapsulation just as easy as composition.  Within there is plenty of evidence of both.  Then again knowing when to apply Demeter's law or not is a question of competant defensive coding not language - there are plenty of sloppy dev's out there for sure.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong about the definition of encapsulation, which is simply bundling together data and the functions that operate on it. So, yes, C# people do mostly use encapsulation. My question then becomes about data hiding, which seems to be being ignored in most C# code (in the manner above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right - you should only return objects from properties where either the object is immutable, or you're happy for the caller to modify it to whatever extent they can. A classic example of this is returning collections - often it's much better to return a read-only wrapper round a collection than to return the "real" collection directly.

On the other hand, pragmatism sometimes calls for just documenting this as "please don't change the returned object" - particularly when it's an API which is only used within a company.

Hopefully there'll be more support for immutability in future versions of C# and .NET, which will make this easier to cope with - but it's likely to remain a knotty problem in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't encapsulation - it's an act of abstraction through object composition or aggregation depending on how the internal object lifetimes are created/managed.

In composition patterns it is perfectly acceptable to access composite state e.g. the instance of A in the instance of B.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

As you point out the semantics of encapsulation are *very different* - to completely hide the internal implementation of A e.g. by inheriting B from A.

Comment: I don't think the idea of composition comments at all on the access level of internal members. It just says that class B holds a "has-a" relationship with class A. That's all.

Comment: Also, encapsulation has got nothing to do with inheriting B from A. It is just about hiding internal details of a class (such as its data members) from the client code. Whether you inherit or use composition or whatever is not relevant vis a vis encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe related to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)... are you talking only about getters and setters that have no extra logic (and thus effectively directly expose the member), or any get-set pairs?  In any case, if this portion of the outer object's state doesn't participate in meaninful invariants on the outer object, I don't think it's necessarily unreasonable to do this.

Comment: Totally agree - Demeter covers abstraction completely - you'd give the "whole toy" composition of B containing A in this instance to play with.  If you don't want them to mess with A should use encapulation rather than abstraction.